# Spacy me pide numpy >= 1.15 mientras que Tensorflow me pide numpy numpy<=1.14.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, spacy

Cloné un rasa chatbot desde [un repositorio Github](https://github.com/NaThemis/Chatbot_RASA_room_reservation) y intento ejecutarle. Sin embargo obtenia un error al descaragar rasa_nlu:

```
>>>pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]
```

Indeed:

```
(chaenv36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\7_2_2019\ChatbotRASA_Room-reservation>pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]
Requirement already satisfied: rasa_nlu[spacy] in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (0.13.7)
Requirement already satisfied: gevent in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: simplejson in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: klein in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.1)
Requirement already satisfied: coloredlogs in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (4.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib~=2.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.5.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn<0.20; extra == "spacy" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.19.1)
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.3.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy; extra == "spacy" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.10 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from gevent->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.4.15)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from requests->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: Twisted>=13.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: incremental in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (17.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from packaging->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: humanfriendly>=4.7 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from coloredlogs->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (4.17)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from coloredlogs->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.5.95)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.1.13)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib~=2.0->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib~=2.0->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib~=2.0->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib~=2.0->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-crfsuite>=0.8.3 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from sklearn-crfsuite; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: regex==2018.01.10 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2018.1.10)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ujson>=1.35 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.35)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: dill<0.3,>=0.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.2.9)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (6.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zope.interface>=4.4.2 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: constantly>=15.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (15.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Automat>=0.3.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: hyperlink>=17.1.1 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyHamcrest>=1.9.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from Twisted>=13.2->klein->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (18.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyreadline; sys_platform == "win32" in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from humanfriendly>=4.7->coloredlogs->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib~=2.0->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack<0.6.0,>=0.5.6 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (1.10.11)
Requirement already satisfied: cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack-numpy<0.4.4 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: toolz>=0.8.0 in c:\users\antoi\documents\programming\nathalie\7_2_2019\chatbotrasa_room-reservation\chaenv36\lib\site-packages (from cytoolz<0.10,>=0.9.0->thinc<6.13.0,>=6.12.1->spacy>2.0; extra == "spacy"->rasa_nlu[spacy]) (0.9.0)
spacy 2.0.18 has requirement numpy>=1.15.0, but you'll have numpy 1.14.5 which is incompatible.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Yet when I am downloading `numpy==1.15` I have a contradiction:

```
(chaenv36) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\7_2_2019\ChatbotRASA_Room-reservation>pip install numpy==1.15
Collecting numpy==1.15
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/d1/2499797c88de95ea3239ad7f6e6a47895fe51aad1aa2a116f50ec9e0ee74/numpy-1.15.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl (13.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 13.5MB 799kB/s
tensorflow 1.10.0 has requirement numpy<=1.14.5,>=1.13.3, but you'll have numpy 1.15.0 which is incompatible.
```

Entonces SpaCy me pido numpy >= 1.15 mientras que tensorflow me pide numpy `numpy<=1.14.5>=1.13.3`. ¿Cómo puedo manejar esta contradicción?

#### Enterno

Utiliso :

- rasa-core==0.12.0
- rasa-nlu==0.13.7

Comment: Supongo que no puedes... Puedes intentar engañar al sistema, instalando numpy 1.15, después spacy, después rasa, después reinstalar numpy 1.14.5 y luego tensorflow. Posiblemente rasa/spacy no funcionará correctamente, aunque igual hay suerte y la característica de la que dependen para exigir numpy 1.15 no la usa nunca tu código. En cualquier caso considero esta solución frágil.

Comment: @abulafia De otra manera estoy listo para despreciar cualquier cosa

Answer (score 0):

La versión 1.13 de tensorflow depende de numpy (>=1.13.3). Probablemente tengas una versión antigua por una instalación anterior, así que tu problema se debería solucionar actualizando tensorflow. Y de paso actualizando pip.